# how to implement loading image when any http request occure

Tags: api, elm

I have implemented the HTTP service request using elm architecture.but i am also want to implement any loading gif image so that user will know that something is happen in the back ground.

can any please help me to implement to this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a property in your model, whether it is loading or not.
Then you can let your `view` reflect the status by show spinner or text, or whatever.

In case of the example at [http example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/http), you can modify 
following code, for example by adding `iswaiting` property in the `Model` ...

In this example, `FetchSucceed` message gets fired when ajax call is complete.

```elm
type alias Model =
  { topic : String
  , gifUrl : String
  , iswaiting : Bool
  }

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    MorePlease ->
      ({ model | iswaiting = True }, getRandomGif model.topic)

    FetchSucceed newUrl ->
      (Model model.topic newUrl False, Cmd.none)

    FetchFail _ ->
      (model, Cmd.none)

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ h2 [] [text model.topic]
    , text <| if model.iswaiting then "waiting" else ""
    , button [ onClick MorePlease ] [ text "More Please!" ]
    , br [] []
    , img [src model.gifUrl] []
    ]
```

You'll have to adjust other parts as well.
But, I hope you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loading gif image on body and make it appear on top of the page by z-index and after http request is completed then delete that image from body.

Comment: i am using elm and i want to know that when http request will complete